# Python redis get list based on timestamp

Tags: python, redis

I am using a stream and that stream stores data with a timestamp as key, to read it back 10 seconds later (this I am using to send push notifications). I was wondering if I could query redis for a list of timestamps in a specific range.

For example: I have a thread running that will get that data from redis every 10 seconds. Let's say there are 7 new messages placed, that means after 10 seconds I'd like to send 7 new push notifications for the messages that were placed in that time (I will check if they are already read, but that's another case).

Just wondering, I am not familiar with redis at all so I hope anyone knows. I am using [this](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a sorted set, in which the score of each member would be the unix timestamp.

To store a new message, use [ZADD](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore):

```
ZADD myzset <timestamp> <data>
```

Then to get the list of the messages stored since a given time, use [ZRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore):

```
# return the messages posted since reference_timestamp
ZRANGEBYSCORE myzset <reference_timestamp> +inf
```

You can delete the messages after they have been sent, using [ZREMRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore)

```
# delete the messages older than reference_timestamp (including those at timestamp)
ZREMRANGEBYSCORE myzset -inf <reference_timestamp>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for